# Search and filter with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-directives

I'm trying to make search filter in Vuejs. So far I have achieved basic search filter and that's all working. Also I have pagination and I'm displaying 10 items per page, and my problem is when I trying to search items on page 2 and so on, search results are not returning, it's only working on the first page.

Here is my code:

```
import pagination from "./pagination.vue";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.getPosts();
  },

  components: {
    pagination: pagination
  },

  data() {
    return {
      postsUrl: "localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",

      posts: [],

      search: "",

      postsData: {
        per_page: 10,

        page: 1
      },

      pagination: {
        prevPage: "",

        nextPage: "",

        totalPages: "",

        from: "",

        to: "",

        total: ""
      }
    };
  },

  computed: {
    filteredList: function() {
      var query = this.search;
      return this.posts.filter(function(post) {
        return (
          post.title.rendered.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        );
      });
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios

        .get(this.postsUrl, { params: this.postsData })

        .then(response => {
          this.posts = response.data;

          this.configPagination(response.headers);
        })

        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Also:

```
 <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.." />
    <label>Search title:</label>
    <div  v-for="post in filteredList" :key="post.id">

          <h4>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h4>

          <p>{{ post.date }}</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: if using pagination and server side data, why do you handle search in frontend and not just doing the search via backend?

Comment: it makes sense to reset current page to first one when you are changing search string. When you are searching you can get, for example, 6 results but if you are in 3rd page you will see nothing.